# Trying to get non-nested list out of nested list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
class Card:
def __init__(self, suit, value):
    self.suit = suit
    self.value = value
def __repr__(self):
    return f"{self.value} of {self.suit}"

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
        values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
        self.cards = [[Card(val, itm) for itm in values] for val in suits] #ISSUE

my_deck = Deck()
```

my_deck.cards is a list containing 4 lists. All 52 cards are there but I want just a simple list with all 52 cards there. How can I rewrite the line with #ISSUE so that it makes a regular list instead of a list containing 4 lists?

Comment: Take away the inner brackets on the list comprehension `[Card(val, itm) for itm in values for val in suits]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steven Rumbalski, I now know that removing the inner square brackets gives me the one-level list that I wanted.

```
self.cards = [[Card(val, itm) for itm in values] for val in suits] #ISSUE
```

Becomes:

```
self.cards = [Card(val, itm) for val in suits for itm in values]
```